# What does "there, there" actually mean?

Tags: conversation

It came from [an episode of *Big Bang Theory*](http://www.google.com.hk/search?q=there%20there%20everything%20is%20going%20to%20be%20fine); when Penny gets hurt, and asks Sheldon to be more comforting, he starts the conversation with "there, there."

What does that mean?

Comment: The odd thing is that, whereas "there, there" is used as an expression of comfort, "now, now" can be used as a mild remonstrance, and "well, well" and "my, my" to express something equivalent to "how about that?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Wiktionary explains it in the best way possible:

> [there, there](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there,_there): (idiomatic) Conveys comfort; used to calm somebody or urge somebody to relax, especially when the person is crying.
>
> > There, there. Even though you broke up with her, you'll be fine.

Comment: The point of having Sheldon use the phrase is that it _doesn't_ convey comfort. It's a platitude, but he's too socially awkward to come up with anything that might actually help Penny.

Comment: In the case of Radiohead's song There There, makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

"There, there" is generally a phrase used while consoling someone. It is usually followed with something that might be able to lift the sad person's spirits. 
It's similar to "now, now."

> There, there, it's okay. We can fix your broken toy.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "there there" you basically use, when you are consoling or trying to console someone   (especially a kid ) with "there there" you are insuring the person everything is alright.
For example: A kid has lost his favorite toy and starts crying.
Mother: " there there....we'll get you a new one"